# Android picture was not added to gallery, but OnScanCompletedListener is called

Tags: android, android-studio, android-gallery

I created an example app, which takes pictures and saves them, by following [this tutorial](https://developer.android.com/training/camera/photobasics#java). Unfortunately the "Add the photo to a gallery" part is not working. I get no error in logcat. The image is just simply not visible in the gallery. Original code:

```
Intent mediaScanIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE);
File f = new File(currentPhotoPath);
Uri contentUri = Uri.fromFile(f);
mediaScanIntent.setData(contentUri);
this.sendBroadcast(mediaScanIntent);
```

I tried to solve it, by calling `MediaScannerConnection.scanFile`:

```
MediaScannerConnection.scanFile(
    getApplicationContext(),
    new String[]{f.getAbsolutePath()},
    null,
    new MediaScannerConnection.OnScanCompletedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onScanCompleted(String path, Uri uri) {
            Log.v("MyActivity", "file " + path + " was scanned successfully: " + uri);
        }
    });
```

I get this result in logcat:

```
file /storage/emulated/0/Android/data/com.example.myapplication/files/Pictures/JPEG_20200804_104708_4760605263689075696.jpg was scanned successfully: content://media/external/file/3524
```

Unfortunately the picture is still not available in the gallery. What do I wrong? How is it possible to debug something like this?

Comment: Can you open an inputstream for the obtained uri and read from it?

Answer (score 0):

Your link tells you:

> > Note: If you saved your photo to the directory provided by getExternalFilesDir(), the media scanner cannot access the files because they are private to your app..

Well everybody -until Q- can get access to that dir but apparently the media scanner closes its eyes for it.

But strange that an uri is returned. Try to open it.

Comment: What should I use instead of `getExternalFilesDir`?

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to save the image to the gallery and it will be visible immediately after it is saved

```
         String name = "image_name";
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.Q) {
            try {
                ContentResolver resolver = getContentResolver();
                ContentValues contentValues = new ContentValues();
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.DISPLAY_NAME, name);
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpg");
                contentValues.put(MediaStore.MediaColumns.RELATIVE_PATH, "Pictures/" + "App Name");
                Uri imageUri = resolver.insert(MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, contentValues);

                OutputStream outputStream = resolver.openOutputStream(Objects.requireNonNull(imageUri));
                int quality = 100;
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
                outputStream.flush();
                outputStream.close();

                sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, imageUri));
              
                
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
                Snackbar.make(v, "Unable to Save image " + e.getMessage(), Snackbar.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }

        }else {
            String fullPath = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() + "/App Name";
            File dir = new File(fullPath);
            if (!dir.exists()) {
                dir.mkdirs();
            }
            File imageFile = new File(fullPath, name);
            FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream(imageFile);
            int quality = 100;
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, quality, outputStream);
            outputStream.flush();
            outputStream.close();

            sendBroadcast(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, Uri.fromFile(imageFile)));
        }
```

Comment: Thank you, but why doesn't the simple example from the tutorial work?

Comment: The example of the tutorial originally used getExternalStorageDirectory where the media scanner has acces. You now used getExternalFilesDir and you know the consequences.